# memcache server losts connection on heavy request through AB (Apache Benchmark)

Tags: caching, memcached, apachebench

We got a really big hit trouble  on mysql server which has 400k rows total and about 220 MB last week so we decided to start using memcache. Before changing whole script a test page has been prepared and tested with apache benchmark (I am not sure if its the correct way to test it)

```
ab -n 50000 -c 150 http://192.168.1.5/test.php
```

When i use the command above to test with more requests memcache starts to disconnect after 25000 request.

Here is the sample code of test.php

```
<?php
global $memcache;
$memcache = new Memcache();

//$memcache->flush();
$memcache->connect("127.0.0.1", "11211");

$key = "10";

$cache_result = $memcache->get($key);

if($cache_result) {
    $data = $cache_result;
    echo "<h1>cache data</h1>";
} else {
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("newstest");
    mysql_set_charset("utf8");

    $q = mysql_query("SELECT * `news`, `categories` WHERE `publish_area` LIKE 'headline' AND `published`='1' AND `category_parent`=`category_id` AND `publish_date` <= '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."' ORDER BY publish_date DESC LIMIT 0,15");

    while($o = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {
        $data[] = $o;
    }

    $memcache->set($key, $data);
    echo "<h1>mysql data</h1>";

    mysql_close();
}

foreach($data as $o) {
    print_r($o);    
}
```

?>

Data pulled from MySQL is about 120 KB

memcached cachesize = 1024 also tried with 2048

memcached maxconn = 4096

It seems the problem caused by high traffic on mysql server will be fixed after memcache but memcache disconnection is the current problem. It seems like this time mysql server will work but memcache will disconnect.

Any idea will be usefull. Thanks.